# Prevent webpack 4 pug loader from compiling mixin files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-4, pug-loader

I'm really new to Webpack 4 and found a configuration issue I can not resolve.

I'm configuring Webpack for a multi page application. HTML template engine is **PUG**.
Files are compiled correctly, but when I create the bundle, Webpack is also compiling the mixins I have at "src/pug/mixins" folders. Therefore I get an .html file from every .pug mixin file I have.

**How can I tell Webpack not to generate an .html file from a mixins located inside a folder?**

I have the following at my webpack.config file:

```
module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            use: ["pug-loader"],
            exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pug/utils')]
        },
```

However, all mixins inside utils folder are converted (i.e: utils/coreMixins.pug -> utils/coreMixins.html )

Thanks for your answers